# SQL query to update list of records by looping through a table records and check some logic?

Tags: sql

I do not want to use cursors for performance reasons. 
Input Parameters for stored procedure: arg1, arg2,arg3 & arg4
For example:
Table A > A1 Column and A2 Column,
Table B > B1 Column (A.A1 <=>B.B1) foreign n primary key relation and B2 Column.

I want to update A.A2 value based on the following if condition,

```
if(arg1 == B.B2 && arg2 == B.B2)
{
   Update A set A.A2 = 1 where A.A1 = arg4
}
else{ 
if(arg1 == 1 && arg3 == B.B2){
 Update A set A.A2 = 0 where A.A1 = arg4
}

}
```

this is simple for one record but the Table A has 1000's records that match A.A1 = arg4 so i have to apply the above logic or case for all records and want to avoid using cursors...how do i do it?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? And are you using a programming language as well (considering your example is not in a standard SQL format).

Comment: So B1 is the primary key of B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below query.

```
 UPDATE tmp
 SET tmp.A2 =
    (CASE WHEN (tmp1.B2 == arg1 && tmp1.B2 == arg2) THEN 1 WHEN (arg1 == 1 && tmp1.B2 == arg3) THEN 0 ELSE tmp.A2)
 FROM
     A tmp
 INNER JOIN
     B tmp1
        ON tmp.A1 = tmp1.B1
 WHERE
      tmp.A1 = arg4
```

Hope this Helps!!

Comment: That completely misses the case of arg1 = 1 AND B.B2 = arg3.

Answer (score 1):

In general, non-specific SQL-92 you could do this:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.A2 = CASE WHEN B.B2 IN (@Arg1,@Arg2) THEN 1
            WHEN @arg1 = 1 AND B.B2 = @arg3 THEN 0 END
FROM A
JOIN B ON A.A1=B.B1
WHERE A.A1 = @arg4
```

You may need an `ELSE` before `END` if you don't want any values falling through (without the `ELSE` it would set A.A2 to `NULL`).